# How to get new image size after changing src in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, resize

I have an image element with a spinner gif.  I later dynamically change the src of that image with jQuery, and I want to get the actual width and height of the new image.  Here is my code:

```
function loadImage() {
$('#uploaded-image').load(function() {
    var img = document.getElementById('uploaded-image');

            // These statements return the correct values in FF and Chrome but not IE
    imgWidth = img.clientWidth;
    imgHeight = img.clientHeight;
});
$('#uploaded-image').removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height').attr('src', imgUrl);
}
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but IE always returns the size of the original spinner gif instead of the new image.

How can I get the width and height of the new image in IE?

**Notes:**

I've tried the jQuery .width() and .height() methods in addition to the pure Javascript approach, with the same results.

The .load event is being fired as expected in all browsers.

Comment: What's really strange is that when inspecting DOM properties in IE's developer tools, even those show the original spinner size rather than the size of the new image.

Comment: In IE developer tool (F12) you need to press that little refresh to DOM get updated

Answer (score 2):

Use `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` in IE.

Check this out in your IE: http://jsbin.com/abopih/5

```
var imgUrl = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
 var img = document.getElementById('uploaded-image');
$('#uploaded-image').click(function() {
    imgWidth = img.clientWidth;
    imgHeight = img.clientHeight;
  $('#uploaded-image').removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height').attr('src', imgUrl);
      console.info('clientWidth: ',  img.clientWidth);
      console.info('clientHeight: ',  img.clientHeight);
      console.info('offsetWidth: ', img.offsetWidth);
      console.info('offsetWidth: ', img.offsetWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hidden div and place the image in there in order to get the size. Just make sure the hidden div isn't done with `display:none`, because then it will have no dimensions. Use `visibility:hidden`, grab the dimensions, and then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove css height and width as well:

```
$('#uploaded-image').css({ height: "auto", width: "auto" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$("#file").change(function(e) {
    var file, img;
    file = document.getElementById("file");
    if (file!=null) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = file.value;
        img.onload = function() {
            alert(img.width + " " + img.height);
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            alert( "not a valid file: " + file.type);
        };
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a cache problem.

Add this to your image source url:

```
imgUrl += new Date().getTime();
```